# What are my options when I am drifting off into space?

Tags: space-station-13

During the process of turning on the field generators for the singularity engine I slipped and drifted off into space.

Is it possible to somehow recover from this and make it back to the station?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've played SS13, so I won't write up a full answer. But if memory serves: you can throw stuff in the direction opposite the one you want to travel to propel yourself (every action has an equal and opposite reaction). This method does require you to start chucking items from your inventory, and I don't recall if the weight of the item thrown has any impact on the resulting speed, so plan your throws well. Typically you'd want to get rid of the least important and most replaceable things first.

Comment: Thanks that actually worked, post it as an answer please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can try if you have no other means of propelling yourself is throwing stuff in the direction opposite the one you want to travel (every action has an equal and opposite reaction). This method does require you to start chucking items from your inventory, and I don't recall if the weight of the item thrown has any impact on the resulting speed, so plan your throws well (granted, depending on your oxygen reserves and how fast you're drifting, 'planning' might not be on your list of priorities).

Typically you'd want to get rid of the least important and most replaceable things first. One 'danger' to this method you might want to be aware of is that there is the slimmest chance your makeshift 'propellant' might coldcock some other person out for a space walk.